# rake assets:precompile is slow in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, assets, production

My ruby on rails app take about half an hour to complete a deployment. 
The longest step is

```
RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

which takes about 1073155ms

I have to wait for a long time for each deployment.

I use

```
ckeditor
rails_admin
```

I guess it is them who slow down my deployment, but I don't evidence and I don't know how to

solve it, either.

My other environments are as follows:

```
rails 4.0.3
ruby 2.1.1
```

My production.rb about assets is

```
config.serve_static_assets = false

# Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
# config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

# Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
config.assets.compile = true

# Generate digests for assets URLs.
config.assets.digest = true

# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
config.assets.version = '1.0'
```

Comment: Checkout https://github.com/spagalloco/capistrano-local-precompile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to skip compiling ckeditor assets

*config/environments/production.rb*

```
  require_relative '../../lib/assets/selective_assets_compressor'
  config.assets.js_compressor = SelectiveAssetsCompressor.new
```

*lib/assets/selective_assets_compressor.rb*

```
class SelectiveAssetsCompressor < Uglifier
  def initialize(options = {})
    super(options)
  end

  def compress(string)
    if string =~ /CKSource/
      string
    else
      super(string)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

For faster asset precompiles, you can setting config.assets.initialize_on_precompile to false in config/application.rb. Heroku requires this to be false.

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

If you do that, be sure to test rake assets:precompile locally because the complete environment is not loaded, engines (or other gems) will not be loaded, which can cause missing assets.

In the other hand you can execute asset precompile before deploy locally and deploy the files precompiled.

Comment: What about precompile locally? It's the best choice because you precompile once and deploy to all your servers precompiled. And your release is ready to run.